# Find the number of files available in Azure data lake directory using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am working on a pipeline where our data sources are csv files stored in Azure data lake. I was able to process all the files using get meta data and for each activity. Now I need to find the number of files available in the Azure data lake? How can we achieve that. I couldn't find any itemcount argument in the Get Meta Data activity. I have noticed that the input of For each activity contains an itemscount value. Is there anyway to access this?

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: How exactly are you analysing this meta data?  Could you add the JSON for your Activity to your question?  Also, *why* do you need to know how many files there are?  What will you do with that number once you have it?

Comment: Hi Dave, I need to log the information into a sql server table. As it will help us to get a better insight into the source data. Right now I am travelling, and need 2 days time to share the json. + sandeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output of a child_items Get Metadata activity is a list of objects, why not just get the length of this list?

`@{length(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems)}`